Is it possible to retrieve Facebook Group members' mailing addresses from any of Facebook's API's (is it Graph API we would use?)
Is it possible to retrieve Facebook Group members' physical mailing addresses from any of Facebook's API's (is it Graph API we would use?)
Can anyone verify?  I know we can get the user's emails but it would seem the mailing addresses would not be available due to privacy concerns.
I have checked through the documentation and found this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/mailing-address/
but digging a bit further it seems this is only for business' mailing addresses.
